# How to get output from mysql in right encoding

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

how can i get MYSQL output in right encoding? I have this escaped string in MYSQL DB: WannahÃ«al, i need Wannahëal.

Thank you!

```
// Connect
$link = mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx') or die("Can't connect to MYSQL DB");
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $link);

//Choose a DB
mysql_select_db('xxx') or die("Can't select MYSQL DB");


$query = "SELECT * FROM mr_characters";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed!');

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
    echo $row->title . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Before worrying about the output, confirm that the data was stored correctly.  Do `SELECT HEX(col)...` to display that value.  ë is hex C3AB; is that what you get?  If you get C383C2AB then you are inflicted with "double encoding".  It means that you did not have the set_charset in effect when you INSERTed the data.  I can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-set-charset.php) to set your client character set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the charset in your charset, I think in your case utf8.

Either you can make this in the creating of your db:

```
CREATE DATABASE myDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
[...]
```

Or in the tables:

```
[...]
CREATE TABLE myTable DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
(
[...]
```

EDIT: If you don't set the charset before you make the data input into your MySQL server, your MySQL server isn't able to read the data correctly and saves them incorrectly. So not your code is incorrect nor your server had an any failure, quite honestly your server saved your data incorrect.